# Gmail API Users.Messages.get return some messages without any label

Tags: gmail-api

Trying to get messages from Gmail using RESTFul API using get operation and some messages are returned empty labels (other parts of the payload are ok).

What is the reason to get empty labels ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like expected behavior.  If they don't have any labels (e.g. not even INBOX) then they are simply in All Mail (e.g. they have been archived and are in the mailbox, etc).

Answer (score 2):

Messages without labels are archived messages.